# Debug with geth

Tags: contract-debugging, geth-debugging, dapp-debugging

I'm trying to debug a failed ether transaction and to understand what went wrong.

The transaction is this one: 
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xaf0eb06c892cbbf75e50afec6d439f748aaed33091798b94a9dd4cc0ed253edd

I tried so far:

```
geth console
debug.traceTransaction('0xaf0eb06c892cbbf75e50afec6d439f748aaed33091798b94a9dd4cc0ed253edd');
```

Got the error: 
[image]

Maybe there is an easier way to find out what went wrong. I also tried to debug with etherscan http://etherscan.io/remix?txhash=0xbb22dde158e7f9025463127267436b8cc3f27877cfb17268fd4045e099ec5770

this looks promising but I can't see the source neither was not able to find out what went wrong.

Comment: I know from the remix IDE that you can step through the source code too. I was expecting to see this work at etherscan too, since the source code for the contract is attached.. Did you try the truffle debugger? -> http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/debugging

Comment: I didn't try it yet, since I was not sure if it is possible to debug a past transaction and analyse what went wrong. As I understood the default setup is on test-environment.

Comment: AFAIK, you can have truffle connected to mainnet too. I didn't try it yet, but it should work.

Comment: OK that sounds promising. Will try it. As I understand in such a case I have to start geth and connect to it with truffle. Is this correct? Or is there an easier way. On the client side I'm using right now infura

Comment: I guess you'll have to start your own node and open the RPC port. I tried it with remix.ethereum.org + infura, but it didn't work. I think infura is not exposing all the necessary APIs.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! I will try it if I find the time. Right now have to clear my hard drive to run the full node...

Comment: Please answer the question here, if you find a way to debug/trace it with the source code. I would like to know if it works or not. *favorited*

Comment: Sure! Will post an answer here if i find a way to do it!

Comment: You'll need to run your own geth node unfortunately. It looks like infura is not currently supporting the `debug` API: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/890 and https://github.com/INFURA/infura/issues/123.